# Partial derivative of product of vector transpose and vector.

Tags: partial-derivative, transpose

While watching "[CS 224D Lecture 2](https://youtu.be/T8tQZChniMk?t=41m51s)" at [41:51](https://youtu.be/T8tQZChniMk?t=41m51s) the professor writes on the  board:

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial v_c}u^T_ov_c=u_o$$

I initially thought the result  was going to be   :

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial v_c}u^T_ov_c=u^T_o$$

Which seems to be the expected result as you are treating $u^T_o$ as a constant.

I searched for other instances of this formula and at "[Derivatives with respect to vectors](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~csip/tirgul3_derivatives.pdf)" Example 3, the author confirms:

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}u^Tx=u^T$$

While not reliable, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%20u%5ET%20x) also gives the above formula.

Question: Why does the Transpose "disappear" in the first formula?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only explanation is, that $u_0$ is a scalar. Therefore $u_0=u_0^T$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a relaxation of notation that is causing your confusion. $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$ when $x$ is a vector means the vector with the $i$th component $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$$
Also, remember $a^Tb$ is shorthand for $$\sum_i a_i b_i$$ so that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}a^Tx = a$$

Comment: So they applied the Einstein’s summation convention; in that case, the last expression in your answer should be $a_i$, which also matches the one the professor wrote $u_o$. Right?

Comment: The notation I've used here and that was used in the question have the indices implicit in them. I've always found this notation to be a bit sloppy. The summation convention is the best notation to make things unambiguous and clear. Using the summation convention, the last line in my answer reads $\partial_j a_i x_i = a_j$, yes.

Comment: Note that in the pdf example you posted in your question the author is using the notation $a_i^T$ to denote the $i$th row of a matrix. If you remember what $a^Tx$ means (just the sum of the products of the components) you can see that the answer of $a^T$ makes sense in each row.